# Connecting to a Remote Oracle Database using Python

Tags: python, django, oracle, oracle10g

How can I connect to a remote Oracle database using Python?

What packages need to be installed?

Comment: Try google before post at SO. The first returned link searching by  "python oracle" is: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html

Comment: :) how to install cx_Oracle in ubuntu

Comment: 1) Download cx_Oracle here http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/ (get the RPM package for your plataform); 2) "sudo apt-get install alien" ; 3) "sudo alien -d cx_Oracle-5.1.x-11g-pyxx-1.xxxx.rpm" ; 4) "sudo dpkg -i cx_Oracle-5.1.x-11g-pyxx-1.xxxx.deb"

Answer (score 2):

Start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#oracle-notes